# Use the pumping lemma for context free languages to prove L = {w#w | w \in {a,b}*} is not context free

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, pumping-lemma

I know the basics of using the pumping lemma for CFG to prove a language L is not context-free, however, the # symbol seems to be throwing me off or my understanding is not complete.

Comment: Replace the '#' with 'c'.  Then can you answer it?

Comment: Can you do it for the language without #? The same proof should work for your language (perhaps with fewer cases to check).